# How to iterate through complex Json object and do something on each property which equals a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I got the following problem,

I need to iterate through a big Json object ( child nodes consist of array's, strings and objects with at least 4-5 layers of depth in terms of nested properties ).

In some parts across the big Json file there is a specific object structure, it has a property named "erpCode". I need to scan the Json and find all the objects with that property, take the value use that code to ask a different API for details and once I get the details insert them into the object with the current 'erpCode'.

Just to clarify, in my case the parent node property name in the Json always equals the value in 'typeSysname' field which located on the same 'level' as the erpCode property.
A simple example :

```
{
   "cars": [
    {
      "name": "X222",
      "carType": {
         "erpCode": "skoda",
         "value": null,
         "typeSysName": "carType"
       }
    }
    ],
    "model": {
       "year": 1999,
       "details": {
           "erpCode": "112"
           "value": null,
           "typeSysName": "details"
        } 
     } 
}
```

In this example I need to find 2 properties get the values skoda and 112 out of them and get the value and description data from a different API and set it into this Json in the right location.

P.S. Any chance there is a good npm package which can help me with that?

Edit: 
I got a solution in C# from a few months ago which runs in a generic way on the Json and handles the complexity of the structure in a generic way.
But I now need to convert this into Javascript and I am a bit lost.

```
public static string TranslateDocErpCodes(string jsonString, string topRetailerSysName)
        {

            try
            {
                var doc = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
                var erpCodeList = doc.SelectTokens("$..erpCode").ToList();

                foreach (var erpCodeJToken in erpCodeList)
                {
                    var value = erpCodeJToken?.Value<string>();
                    var erpCodeParent = erpCodeJToken?.Parent.Parent;
                    var erpCodeProperty = erpCodeParent?.Path.Split(".").Last();

                    var result =
                        _dataService.GetLovFromErpCode(topRetailerSysName, erpCodeProperty, value);

                    if (result == null)//reset lov obj
                    {
                        if (erpCodeParent?.Parent is JProperty prop)
                            prop.Value = JObject.FromObject(new LovObject { ErpCode = value });
                    }
                    else//set lov obj
                    {
                        result.ErpCode = value;
                        if (erpCodeParent?.Parent is JProperty prop)
                            prop.Value = JObject.FromObject(result);
                    }

                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("ErpConvert.TranslateDocErpCodes() : " + e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Should the second object be inside the `cars` array?

Comment: maybe something like that might work https://github.com/nahid/jsonq ?

Comment: Wrong language @SercanPaspal.

Comment: nope, basically the Json is quite complex, it is an object and it contains multiple array's and objects and simple strings, and inside of those it contains more objects and array's. I actually got a working C# solution but I now need to "convert" it into node.js and I am having problems doing so.

Comment: What's your C# Solution? Can you edit it into your question?

Comment: you can use http://jsonata.org/ it is Lightweight query and transformation language for JSON data . that will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the answer from Aravindh as a starting point and managed to reach what seems to be a complete solution.
I will share it here,

```
async function convertErpCodes(jsonData, orgName, parentPropertyName){    
        for (let prop in jsonData) {
          if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
              if (prop === 'erpCode') {
                  const erpCodeValue = jsonData[prop]
                  const req = {"query": {"erpCode": erpCodeValue, "orgName": orgName, "typeSysName": parentPropertyName}};
                  const result = await viewLookupErpService.findOne(req);
                  if(result)
                    return result; 
              }
              const curValue = jsonData[prop];
              if (Array.isArray(curValue)) {
                  for(let i in curValue){
                    const res = await convertErpCodes(curValue[i], orgName, prop);
                  }
              } else if (curValue && typeof curValue === 'object') {
                const response = await convertErpCodes(curValue, orgName, prop);
                if(response){
                    jsonData[prop] = response;
                }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

P.S. 
I set up the values only if I get a response from the third party API ( this is the reason for the result and response logic in the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

mb something like;

```
function processObject(jsonData) {
    for (prop in jsonData) {
        if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            // We get our prop
            if (prop === 'code') {
                let codeValue = jsonData[prop]
                doSomeAsync(codeValue)
                    .then(response => {
                        jsonData[prop] = response;
                    })
            }
            let curValue = jsonData[prop];
            if (Array.isArray(curValue)) {
                // Loop through the array, if array element is an object, call processObject recursively.
                processArray(curValue);
            } else if (typeof curValue === 'object') {
                processObject(curValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) and [lodash.set](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.set) in combination

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');
// const lodash = require('lodash');

const stats = { cars: [{ name: 'X222', carType: { erpCode: 'skoda', value: null, typeSysName: 'carType' } }], model: { year: 1999, details: { erpCode: '112', value: null, typeSysName: 'details' } } };

const entries = objectScan(['**.erpCode'], { rtn: 'entry' })(stats);
console.log(entries);
// => [ [ [ 'model', 'details', 'erpCode' ], '112' ], [ [ 'cars', 0, 'carType', 'erpCode' ], 'skoda' ] ]

// where you would query the external api and place results in entries
entries[0][1] = 'foo';
entries[1][1] = 'bar';

entries.forEach(([k, v]) => lodash.set(stats, k, v));
console.log(stats);
// => { cars: [ { name: 'X222', carType: { erpCode: 'bar', value: null, typeSysName: 'carType' } } ], model: { year: 1999, details: { erpCode: 'foo', value: null, typeSysName: 'details' } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/lodash@4.17.20"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)